# How do I prove this theorem?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Being $K$ a field. If $\deg(a_i, K)$ and $\deg(a_j, K)$ are co-prime for all $i,j \in \{1, ..., n\}$ with $i \neq j$, then
$[K(a_1, ..., a_n) : K] = \prod_{i = 1}^{n} \deg(a_i, K)$

Comment: Hint: $[K(a_i):K]$ divides $[K(a_1,a_2,...,a_n):K]$ for every $i$.

Comment: A way to do: do the case $n=2$ and use the fact that $K(a_1,...,a_{n-1})=K(b)$ for some $b$ to get the general case by induction.

Comment: @Jérémy Blanc: It is true in fact that the composite extension is simple if all of the given ones are (since at most one is non-separable). But the statement holds even if the initial extension are not necessarily simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Claim: Let $k$ be a field, $f(x) \in k[x]$ be irreducible monic of degree $n \geq 1,$ $K$ be an extension of $k$ with $[K:k] = m$ where $\text{gcd}(m, n) = 1.$ Then $f(x)$ is irreducible over $K.$

Let $\alpha$ be a root of $f(x)$ in some extension of $k.$ Then $[K(\alpha):k] = [K(\alpha):K][K : k] = m[K(\alpha):K]$ and $[K(\alpha):k] = [K(\alpha): k(\alpha)][k(\alpha):k] = n[K(\alpha):k(\alpha)].$ So $mn|[K(\alpha):k].$ From this it follows that $f(x)$ is irreducible over $K$ also.

Now use the above claim and induction to show that $[K(a_1, ..., a_n) : K] = \prod_{i = 1}^{n} \deg(a_i, K).$